# Output Issues with pandas, Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

#### Begin Code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/lhicks/Documents/Corporate/test.csv', 'r')
saved_column = df.FirstName
saved_column2 = df.LastName
saved_column3 = df.Email

print saved_column
print saved_column2
print saved_column3


Itemlist = [] 
Itemlist.append(saved_column)


print Itemlist
```

#### End of Code

The objective is to select specific columns from a specified xls sheet, grab all the rows from the specified columns, and then print that data out.

The current issue is the data is grabbed correctly, but after 29-30 rows, it prints/stores a "...", and then jumps to line item 880s, and finishes out from there.

The additional issue is that it also stores this as the value, making it worthless due to not providing the full dataset.

The eventual process is to add the selected columns to a new xls sheet to clean up the old data, and then add the rows to a templated document to generate an advertisement letter.

The first question is how to I have all the fields populate? The second is what is the best approach for this? Please provide additional links as well if possible, this is a practical learning experience for me.

Answer (score 4):

Pandas tries to shorten your data when **printing** it.

NOTE: all the data is still there (`print(df.shape)` - to check it, print the shape of your DataFrame), it's just a convenient way not to flood your screen with tons of data rows/columns

Try this:

```
fn = 'C:/Users/lhicks/Documents/Corporate/test.csv'
cols = ['FirstName','LastName','Email']
df = pd.read_csv(fn, usecols=cols)

df.to_excel('/path/to/excel.xlsx', index=False)
```

This will parse only `['FirstName','LastName','Email']` columns from a CSV file and will export them to Excel file

**UPDATE:**

if you want to [control how many rows should Pandas print](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html):

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows",200):
    print(df)
```

Comment: https://memesuper.com/download/c0c7b175909d330984185c3ae11d090675c22199.html

what do you people eat for breakfast, and can I get that in an IV drip?

Comment: @Fallenour, that's funny :-)